# JQuery: return values to load callback function

Tags: jquery, html

It's required to partial upload Html page with `$(selector).load('/sitePath', params, function() { ... });` method. Html layout comes ok but it would be nice to return some additional values for javascript also.

Nowadays I return special javascript block with javascript variables inside html layout to read their values on load callback. What is the best practice to perform such operation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for `JSON` and `.ajax()`.

```
$.ajax({
   url:      '/sitePath',
   dataType: 'json',
   type:     'POST',
   data:     params,
   success:  function(data){
       $(selector).html(data.newcontent);
       var info = data.additionalinfo;
   }
});
```

Of course assumes that you create a `JSON` string on your server that helds both, a property named `newcontent` which should contain `html markup` and a property named `additionalinfo`.

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to refactor this to load method?

Comment: @Andrew: unfortunatly not, `.load()` is a wrapper for `.ajax()` which automatically loads the received content into the selected element. That is the purpose of this method. To have more controll you need to deal with the underlying `.ajax()` method.

Comment: It's so pity. I have to use classic ASP.NET (not MVC) application in a project and use aspx page to createpartially loaded html layout. This page heavily relies on asp: controls. That's why I hesitate about layout to json conversions.

Comment: @Andrew: well, another way to receive some kind of `data` among the actually html/markup is to send a second request. One with `.load()` and another `.get()` for instance to receive data. Not that elegant tho.